# Python Debugger Not Working When Selecting 3.11 Interpreter But Works For 3.7 Interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

This is my code

```
class Solution:
    def add(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        z = x + y
        t = 5 + x + y

        return z


x = Solution()
print(x.add(1, 3))
```

And I have breakpoints set at the `print` line and `t = 5 + x + y`.

These are my interpreters:
[image]

If I use python 3.7 and hit F5, everything works fine.
If I select any of the other 2 (I would prefer the `interview_env` one) and hit F5, the program does not run and the breakpoints are not hit. What is going on and how do I solve this?

I am using a virtual environment that was sent to me and needs to be used for an interview so I need to make sure I can debug in that environment.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Is Python 3.11 installed on your machine? Does the file `~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` exist? If not, install it first.

Comment: Does `.\interview_env\Scripts\python.exe` point to an existing and working `python.exe`? If not, change it, to point to the correct one.